# регулярное выражение для BTC-address

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Хочу проверить на валидность адрес криптовалюты. 
Вот пример адреса: 15DQ4VCLvidYRsPjVKwxgntFrta16Kgikv
Здесь от 27 до 34 цифр и букв латинского алфавита вперемежку.
Есть вот такое регулярное выражение:

```
 preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{27,34}+/i", $a);
```

Оно работает но не совсем корректно, т.к. адрес не может состоять только из цифр или только из букв. Подскажите как написать регулярное выражение на проверку и цифр и букв в одной строке.

Comment: а есть точные формальные требования к адресу? Спецификация например? Иначе думаю проще не регуляркой проверять а соответствующее API использовать.

Comment: @pavel формальные требования: начинается с 1 всегда, алфавит - Base58, а именно 123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz

Comment: я хотел придумать универсальную регулярку для разный криптовалют. Вот пример DASH: Xwkbw3s8Rkz23feTBPpMyCYhb3aZWnpEag

Comment: подскажите как сделать регулярку на цифры + буквы в одной строке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такая регулярка сделает именно так, как вы хотите:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[\da-zA-Z]{27,34}$
```

В начале решулярки идут два просмотра вперед нулевой ширины, которые убеждаются, что в строке далее где то есть хотя бы одна цифра и хотя бы одна буква.

Она работает так, как вы сформулировали задачу. Но, как вам уже писали выше, для проверки адресов она не годится, потому как может быть абсолютно нормальный, валидный, адрес состоящий только из цифр или только из букв.

Comment: спасибо огромное, помогли. Для PHP: "/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[\da-zA-Z]{27,34}+/i"

Answer (score 2):

Ваш regexp некорректен: адреса кошельков начинаются с "1", используемый алфавит уже вашего, а именно "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz". Дополнительно, последние 4 байта "сырого" адреса являются проверочными (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses) но в regexp вы это вряд ли запихаете.
Есть еще новые адреса, они начинаются с "3", но я о них ничего не знаю.
PS. Адрес вполне может состоять только из цифр и только из букв, кроме первой. Вероятность мала, но все же есть.

Comment: я хотел придумать универсальную регулярку для разный криптовалют. Вот пример DASH: Xwkbw3s8Rkz23feTBPpMyCYhb3aZWnpEag

Comment: подскажите как сделать регулярку на цифры + буквы в одной строке.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра но не выйдет: у BTC формат свой, например.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра не знаю, я бы даже не заморачивался на regexp: длина всегда постоянна, маркер начала есть. Потом base58-to-bin и проверка по проверочным байтам.

Comment: их всех объединяет количество символов и цифры+буквы.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра Ну удачи...